# Почему я должен использовать break с оператором switch?

Tags: java, switch

Почему я всегда должен использовать `break` с оператором `switch`?

```java
switch (foo) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
        bar();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Например, здесь и при 0, и при 1 вызывается метод `bar()`?

Comment: Уточните вопрос - "Почему я всегда должен использовать", но в примере вы же break с "0" не используете.

Comment: Я там не написал чтоб показать что без break , если foo==0 , то метод bar() вызывается , хочу узнать почему ?

Comment: Да, но вопрос -"Почему я **всегда должен**". Вы не должны всегда использовать break, вы можете его использовать. Наверное вы хотели спросить - В каких случаях его нужно использовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Свитч сделан таким образом, что при нахождении нужного элемента он "проваливается". Например, у вас есть свитч из 10 цифр от 1 до 10. Когда вы передадите для сравнения 5 , то свитч будет сравнивать по порядку с 1,2,3,4,5. В этот момент значения совпадут и дальше, если не будет указан брейк, выполнится код , в 5,6,7,8,9,10 кейсе. У вас в кейсе 0 брейка нет, вот и выполняется ваш метод. добавьте брейк и все будет ок.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно будет понятнее, если рассматривать "case x:" как точку "входа", войдя в которую, вы "падаете" через набор команд. Команда "break" - "прекращает" ваше "падение"(если это нужно). Вот наглядный пример

```
public class SwitchExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte x = (byte)(Math.random()*10); //случайный этаж
        System.out.println("Выпал из окна " + x + " этажа");
        x--;//падаем через этажи, расположенные ниже
        switch (x) {
            case 9:System.out.println("Пролетаю 9 этаж"); 
            case 8:System.out.println("Пролетаю 8 этаж"); 
            case 7:System.out.println("Пролетаю 7 этаж");  
            case 6:System.out.println("Пролетаю 6 этаж");  
            case 5:System.out.println("Пролетаю 5 этаж"); 
                   System.out.println("зацепились - ниже не падаем"); 
                   break;
            case 4:System.out.println("Пролетаю 4 этаж"); 
            case 3:System.out.println("Пролетаю 3 этаж"); 
            case 2:System.out.println("Пролетаю 2 этаж"); 
            case 1:System.out.println("Пролетаю 1 этаж"); 
            case 0:System.out.println("На земле"); 
                   break;//ниже земли не падаем
            default:System.out.println("Странно"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Почему я всегда должен использовать break с оператором switch?

Очевидно, чтобы указать компилятору где кончается обработка каждого case.