# Почему при использовании switch в Java, при совпадении с первым case, выводятся все case-ы

Tags: java, switch

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int monthNumber = 3;

        switch (monthNumber) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("January");
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Feb");
            case 3:
                System.out.println("March");
        }
    }
}
```

попробуйте заменить номер переменной на 1, затем на 2, затем на 3. Посмотрите на разницу вывода

Comment: break; надо использовать

Comment: свитч не очень удачная конструкция в языке, требуется явно выходить из блока.

Comment: См. [Java - Почему я должен использовать break с оператором switch?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/743515/1365)

Comment: @Roman C почему "явно выходить из блока" - это "не очень удачная конструкция" ? Я думаю это удобно и правильно

Comment: @RomanC, не во всех языках так, в delphi не надо писать break; В oracle sql могут быть два одинаковых case, конструкция требующая break гибче.

Comment: Разве не дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743515/java-Почему-я-должен-использовать-break-с-оператором-switch

Comment: @nikoshi Для того, чтобы выйти из блока надо явно ставить `break;` именно это я имел ввиду, насколько это удобно и правильно это ИМХО.

Comment: @NMD Такого языка нет "delphi", это среда программирования или название продукта .

Comment: @Roman C я изначально понял, что вы имели в виду, но не смог представить ситуации, где был бы полезен switch с case неявно содержащими break. Удобство же и правильность на мой взгляд можно представить простым примером: не зависимо от того в какой кейс мы вошли -  выполнить остальные кейсы до конца (или же выйти из switch на каком-то case осуществив проверку). То есть мы можем с помощью: break, return, throw настраивать переключатель, а по умолчанию он выполнит все case как конвейер.

Comment: @nikoshi В этом и проблема, что такого switch case-а не существует в языке Java. С другой стороны зачем выполнять блоки в которых значение переменной ожидается другим? Если в case блоке не стоит явно выход, то это является плохой практикой и источником ошибок. switch создали как упрощение if-else-if конструкций, в которых не требуется явный выход из блока. Ещё один пример тернарный оператор, тоже без явного выхода. JSTL без явного выхода. Если надо выполнить несколько case-ов, то нужно использовать цикл.

Comment: Вообще, у меня такое впечатление, что swtich - это отголосок сишного goto. Получается, что кейсы - это просто метки, на которые происходит переход из начала конструкции switch, а не полноценные блоки кода, поэтому чтобы не проваливаться в следующую метку/кейс, нужно явно выходить из switch.

Comment: @Roman C вот простой надуманный пример :  есть договор из 10 пунктов и нужно реализовать такую логику: заполнить все пункты договора до конца,  но с какого пункта начать неизвестно (или заполнить определённые пункты и прекратить).  Если взять switch содержащий 10 case каждый из которых заполняет соответствующий пункт договора и не использовать break - задача легко решается. Как вы решите эту задачу с помощью if-else или цикла? И будет ли код читаем если решите? Это к вопросу "С другой стороны зачем выполнять блоки в которых значение переменной ожидается другим?"

Comment: @Roman C  Насчёт “switch создали как упрощение if-else-if конструкций…” можно источник в виде ссылки? Насколько я знаю реализация этих операторов различна и switch эффективнее и чаще более удобочитаем. В тернарном операторе уже заложен “выход” в виде возвращаемого значения. В JSTL  это так реализовали возможно из за специфики библиотеки. Ну и конечно эти обсуждения не уместны для Java версии 12+ , там со switch совсем другая история.

Comment: @nikoshi См. [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1312588/204920), там я более детально рассказал и процитировал различие. Про оператор `break` там тоже сказано, если вы не согласны то, мне больше нечего добавить.

Comment: @RomanC, видимо embarcadero тоже этого не знаю, так что напиши им пусть исправят http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Delphi_Language_Reference

Comment: @NMD я не знаю что такое embarcadero, когда я работал с Borland Delphi, язык назывался Object Pascal. Вот [здесь](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_(software)) это написано.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему я должен использовать break с оператором switch?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743515/java-%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-break-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-switch)

Answer (score 5):

В каждом блоке `case` можно использовать оператор `break`, чтобы прерывать выполнение кода в текущем блоке `case`. Оператор `break` не является обязательным, если его нет в блоке `case` – происходит "провал" (передаётся управление) в следующий блок `case` и происходит выполнение кода в этом блоке. Такие "провалы" происходят пока не встретится оператор `break` или до конца оператора `switch`. Если же оператор `break` присутствует - выполнение передаётся за пределы оператора `switch` (выход из `switch`)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int monthNumber = 3;

    switch (monthNumber) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("January");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Feb");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("March");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: но почему с case 2 и case 3 не происходят провалы? или это исключение только для 1 кейса?

Comment: то есть меня интересует, почему когда например подходит case 2 не происходит провал в case 3? например monthNumber = 2
OUTPUT :
Feb
March 

почему вот такой вывод тогда не происходит?

Comment: Если вы не используете break у вас при monthNumber = 2 будет OUTPUT : Feb March. Если вы используете break у вас при monthNumber = 2 будет OUTPUT : Feb. Когда встречается оператор break, тогда прерывается выполнение всего switch

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что вы не используете команду для *явного* выхода из блока. Например `break`, `return`, `throw`, `exit`, `goto`. Последняя команда, больше похожа на реализацию самого оператора `switch`, в котором после вычисления выражения в скобках происходит переход на метку, которая имеет название case со значением. Метка не может передать управление при выходе из case-а, она лишь указывает на строку. Поэтому в блоке switch утверждение case и default - это просто метки, и после перехода на соответствующую метку оставшаяся часть кода в блоке выполняется независимо от того какой case-значение стоит.

Более подробно про switch можно почитать в [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

> Тело оператора switch известно как блок переключения.  Оператор в блоке switch может быть помечен одним или несколькими регистрами или метками по умолчанию.  Оператор switch оценивает свое выражение, затем выполняет все операторы, следующие за соответствующей меткой case.
>
> Вы также можете отображать название месяца с помощью операторов if-then-else:
>
> ```
> int month = 8;  
> if (month == 1) {System.out.println ("Январь");  } 
> else if (month == 2) {System.out.println ("Февраль");  } 
> //... и так дале
> ```
>
> Решение о том, использовать ли операторы if-then-else или оператор switch, основывается на удобочитаемости и выражении, которое проверяется оператором.  Оператор if-then-else может проверять выражения на основе диапазонов значений или условий, тогда как оператор switch проверяет выражения только на основе одного целого числа, перечислимого значения или объекта String.
>
> Еще один интересный момент - это оператор break.  Каждый оператор break завершает включающий оператор switch.  Поток управления продолжается с первого оператора, следующего за блоком switch.  Операторы break необходимы, потому что без них операторы в блоках switch не справляются: все операторы после соответствующей метки case выполняются последовательно, независимо от выражения последующих меток case, до тех пор, пока не встретится оператор break.

Comment: [Что означает если ответ "принят"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)